# Migrate an existing Oracle database to a different charset

Tags: sql, oracle, collation

Whats the best way to migrate an existing Oracle database to a different charset?

I have searched through the [Oracle Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch10.htm) and found two approaches, "Full Export and Import" and an `ALTER DATABASE`.

Comment: What is the source and the destination character set?  Is the destination a strict binary superset of the source?  What version of Oracle?  Have you run the character set scanner?  Is your downtime window large enough to make exporting and importing the data an option?

Comment: Are you wanting to permanently change your charset? We use .dms for our exports and imports to change our charsets in PeopleSoft while our database remains in English. Have you referenced Oracle's Metalink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you migrate use CSSCAN tool to find possible problems. 
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/CharacterSetMigration.php